# Call Change event of a DDL when DDL value is modified from some outside resource

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to call change event in JQuery of a dropdown list when dropdown value has been modified from some outside resource?

Below code works well if I change the value from dropdown list.

```
<select name="month" id="month">
   <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
   <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
</select>


$('#month').change(function () {
        var data = $(this).val();
        alert(data);
    });
```

But It does not call change event when I change the value of dropdown like given below code.

```
$("#month").val('Jan');
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: `.check` isn't the dropdown list. Change that to `#month` and your existing code will work.

Comment: @DanielBeck Sorry.. My bad, I have changed the ID of dropdown above.But it was correct in my code.

Comment: @DanielBeck As mentioned It works only when I click on dropdown and change the value. But I want to trigger change event even if the value of dropdown has been changed from my javascript code.

Comment: I see you've deleted the part of the question that fired the change event, so I guess I'll undelete my answer that explained you needed to do that (which I had deleted once I noticed you already were doing it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change events are only fired when user-initiated, not when the value is changed via code:

> http://api.jquery.com/val/  Setting values using this method (or using the native value property) does not cause the dispatch of the change event. For this reason, the relevant event handlers will not be executed. If you want to execute them, you should call .trigger( "change" ) after setting the value.

You need to manually fire the event in those cases, using either  `.trigger("change")` or the shorthand equivalent `.change()`:

```js
$('#month').change(function() {
  var data = $(this).val();
  console.log(data);
});

// change the select value, and trigger the change event:
$("#month").val('Feb').trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="month" id="month">
  <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
  <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
</select>
```